# Why people are downvoting this question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-question

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with this question?
People are down voting it and I am not getting any comments telling the reason.

[Which technology would be good to use to calculate strength of a currency](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/392735/which-technology-would-be-good-to-use-to-calculate-strength-of-a-currency)

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Each site has its own meta, where the active users of that specific site can give better answers about specific questions from that site. In your case the meta is https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ but keep in mind people don't like "why this is downvoted" in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you post a question on *any* Stack Exchange site, it's good to check the Help Center article [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Some questions, even if they appear to fit into one of the above categories, may still be off-topic or a poor fit for this format:
>
> ...
>
> - [finding or recommending products or services, including tools, libraries or packages, programming languages, books, scholarly papers, tutorials, articles, or blogs](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)

That explains the close votes (which you can't see, since you don't have [250 reputation yet](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)) and on Software Engineering Stack Exchange, such questions are often downvoted as well, presumably because there are so many of them.